# I want to send the value of an object to the server

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, nuxt.js

## What I want to come true

I am creating an app. View is Nuxt and server is Rails.
I can't register the text as I want.

I am registering book information.
There are multiple pieces of information that I want to register, and the content and status of post_items_attributes are multiple, but only one can be registered. What should I do in this case?
If you set it to 0, you can only register one, so I don't know what to do.

```js
    this.$axios.$post(url.POST_API + 'posts', {
      post: {
        title: this.$title(selectedBook),
        author: this.$author(selectedBook),
        image: this.$image(selectedBook),
        post_items_attributes: [{
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
          content: list[0].content, 
          status: list[0].status
////////////////////////////////////////////////
        }]
      }
    })
      .then((responseBook) => {
        context.commit('book/userBook', responseBook)
        context.commit('book/clearBook')
        context.commit('todos/clear')
      })
  },
```

**this.$store.state.todos.list**

```js
export const state = () => ({
  list: []
})
```

[image]

**In list**

## Code

**Nuxt**

```js
    const list = context.state.todos.list
    const selectedBook = context.state.book.selectedBook

    // plugin/bookInfo  $title,$author,$image
    this.$axios.$post(url.POST_API + 'posts', {

    // send　to Rails
      post: {
        title: this.$title(selectedBook),
        author: this.$author(selectedBook),
        image: this.$image(selectedBook),
        post_items_attributes: [{
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
          content: list[0].content,
          status: list[0].status
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        }]
      }
    })
      .then((responseBook) => {
        context.commit('book/userBook', responseBook)
        context.commit('book/clearBook')
        context.commit('todos/clear')
      })
  },
```

**Rails**

```rb
    def create
        posts = Post.new(post_params)
        if posts.save
            render json: 'OK', status: 200
        else
            render json: 'EEEOR', status: 500
        end
    end

        private
         def post_params
            params.require(:post).permit(:title, :author, :image, post_items_attributes: [:id, :content, :status])
         end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't give example of `list` in the question code. But from the context, I conclude that this is an array of JS objects. So you can map it like this:

```js
let post_items_attributes =
  list.map(item => {
    return {
      content: item.content,
      status: item.status,
    }
  })
```

And then pass it in the `post`:

```js
post: {
  title: this.$title(selectedBook),
  author: this.$author(selectedBook),
  image: this.$image(selectedBook),
  post_items_attributes: post_items_attributes
}
```

Or you can do it inline without this variable

Comment: Thank you for your comment.Previously, "[]" was required to send a value to Rails.Why is "[]" no longer needed after creating post_items_attributes?

Comment: If `list` is empty array, `post_items_attributes` will be empty array too